Velleman's proof that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable
I'm reading Velleman's How to Prove It and on p. 320 he inserts a proof that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable that uses the familiar diagonal argument, but is somewhat different than the other proofs that one usually sees. The bit of the proof I am confused about is the following:
Velleman sets out to define a function $f : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+) \to \mathbb{R}$ and show that it is one-to-one. He then notes that, if $\mathbb{R}$ were countable, then there would exist a one-to-one function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}^+$. But then $g \circ f$ would be a one-to-one function from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$, which cannot be the case because $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ is uncountable by Cantor's theorem.
I think I'm failing to clearly grasp the logical structure of the argument. Why is the injectivity of $f$ sufficient to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable? Why is it even necessary to define $f$ in the first place? Wouldn't it suffice to argue that, since $g \circ f$ cannot be one-to-one because of Cantor's theorem, by modus tollens $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable?

You suggest it is not necessary to define a function $f$, but then you also say it suffices to observe $g \circ f$ cannot be one-to-one (which is a statement that is impossible to make unless you already have some $f$).

The argument of Vellman is proof by contradiction: Suppose $\mathbb{R}$ is countable, then there is an injective function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^+$, and we can use this function to build a new function that is an injective function from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$, which we already know is impossible (hence a contradiction). The $f$ function (which actually exists) is used in the construction of the new function.

@Michael So the argument is: suppose that $\mathbb{R}$ is countable and that there exists a function $f : \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{Z}^+) \to \mathbb{R}$, which we are going to prove is injective. Then there must exist an injective function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}^+$. But this would mean that $g \circ f : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+) \to \mathbb{Z}^+$ is also injective, which must be false due to Cantor's theorem. Hence $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable. And we need to prove that $f$ is injective because the only way for $g \circ f$ to be injective is if both $g$ and $f$ are injective, correct?

Sort of. But, as you have written it in the above comment, the contradiction only contrdicts the assertion that "$\mathbb{R}$ is countable and there exists an injective function $f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$." So at least one part of this assertion must be false, and we do not know if the faulty assertion is that $\mathbb{R}$ is countable, or that there is an injective function $f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. To clarify, I would make the fact about $f$ a separate lemma, or as a self-contained part of the proof (not an assumption).

Yes, I should have been more careful. Got it. Thanks for your help!
